# How to join 2 values from different tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I'm a beginner in MySQL, so I need help. 
I want to get values of `name` column from table `role` to show it together with information from `users` instead `id_role`.
How can I realize it? What should the query I write? 
Can you attach the link with solve?

The picture for explanation.
[image: click to see]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT `users`.*,`role`.name as role FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `role` ON `users`.id_role= `role`.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Read more here about [SQL JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
SELECT users.*, role.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN role ON users.id_role = role.id;
```